# Messages are not getting stored in DLQ when Lambda function gets failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a DLQ configured to store messages when Lambda function gets failed.

Lambda Console Snippet -

[image]

Configuration in Lambda-

[image]

DLQ configuration -

[image]

Code Snippet:-

[image]

But message count is always 0 in DLQ, it's not increasing. 
Where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamda failure messages are only put in DLQ if the lambda was invoked `asynchronously`

You can invoke your lambda asynchronously by specifying `--invocation-type Event` using aws sdk i.e.

```
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name my-function  --invocation-type Event --payload '{ "key": "value" }' response.json
{
    "StatusCode": 202
}
```

For more information you can read the [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html)

Comment: It worked. I invoked the lambda function the way you suggested, after that I had to make some changes in policies of user in IAM.